# Java: load c++ dll with char** and callback as parameters

Tags: java, c++, dll, jna

I want to read some functions from a c++ dll in java.

This is a part of the dll code in c++:

```
typedef void(*E1)(int P1, char * P2);
__declspec(dllimport) void S11(int id, char* P1, E1 callback);
__declspec(dllimport) void Get_P1(int id, char** P1);
```

And this is the code to read the dll in java:

```java
interface InterestingEvent
{
    public void interestingEvent(int id, String P1);
}

class Callback implements InterestingEvent {
    @Override
    public void interestingEvent(int id, String P1) {
        System.out.print("The the event "+ id + " throw this error: " + P1 + "\n");
    }
}
public class Main{

public interface Kernel32 extends Library {
    public void S11(int id, String P1, InterestingEvent callback);
    public void Get_P1(int id, String[] P1);
    }

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Kernel32 lib = (Kernel32) Native.loadLibrary("path\\to\\dll",
            Kernel32.class);
    lib.S11(id, "some string", new Callback() );
    }
}
```

And it returns me this error:

```java
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported argument type com.company.Callback at parameter 2 of function S11
```

what am I doing wrong?

And in the Get_P1 method a value is assigned to the parameter P1 and when return I want it to keep that value, similar to the parameters out in C#. What would be the correct way to invoke this method?

Comment: One level of indirection is understandable to non-C++ apps, since it just means "a pointer to a buffer of `T`" if the parameter is a `T*`.  However two or more levels of indirection is not so clear cut.  What does that `char **` supposed to denote?  What does the `Get_P1` function look like?

Comment: The Get_P1 function only loads a structure, get a string field and returns it in parameter P1, so the parameter P1 must retain its value similar to the parameters out in C#.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `InterestingEvent` interface needs to extend JNA's [`Callback`](https://jna.java.net/nonav/javadoc/com/sun/jna/Callback.html) interface (so rename your `Callback` class to something else).  See [Callbacks, Function Pointers and Closures](https://github.com/java-native-access/jna/blob/master/www/CallbacksAndClosures.md) for more details.

As for the 2nd parameter of `Get_P1()`, use [`PointerByReference`](https://jna.java.net/javadoc/com/sun/jna/ptr/PointerByReference.html) instead of `String[]`.  See [Using ByReference Arguments](https://github.com/java-native-access/jna/blob/master/www/ByRefArguments.md) for more details.  In this case, you can use [`PointerByReference.getValue()`](https://jna.java.net/javadoc/com/sun/jna/ptr/PointerByReference.html#getValue()) to get a [`Pointer`](https://jna.java.net/javadoc/com/sun/jna/Pointer.html) representing the returned `char*` value, and then you can convert that to a `String` using [`Pointer.getString()`](https://jna.java.net/javadoc/com/sun/jna/Pointer.html#getString(long)).

Try this:

```
import com.sun.jna.Library;
import com.sun.jna.Native;
import com.sun.jna.Callback;
import com.sun.jna.ptr.PointerByReference;

interface InterestingEvent extends Callback
{
    public void interestingEvent(int id, String P1);
}

class MyCallback implements InterestingEvent {
    @Override
    public void interestingEvent(int id, String P1) {
        System.out.print("The the event "+ id + " throw this error: " + P1 + "\n");
    }
}

public class Main{

    public interface Kernel32 extends Library {
        public void S11(int id, String P1, InterestingEvent callback);
        public void Get_P1(int id, PointerByReference P1);
        }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Kernel32 lib = (Kernel32) Native.loadLibrary("path\\to\\dll",
                Kernel32.class);
        lib.S11(id, "some string", new MyCallback() );

        PointerByReference p = new PointerByReference();
        lib.Get_P1(id, p);
        String str = p.getValue().getString(0);
    }
}
```